# KtLint Execution failed for task ':app:ktlintAndroidTestDebugSourceSetCheck'

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew, ktlint

I am using gradle version 7.0.0-beta01 and following [this guide](https://thiagolopessilva.medium.com/configuring-and-running-ktlin-on-android-studio-990ce19b50b6) to setup KtLint to my project. But I am facing error while running following command

```
./gradlew ktlintFormat
```

Running with `-stacktrace` etc also doesn't seem to help much. Here is the error I am getting. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:ktlintAndroidTestDebugSourceSetFormat'.
> Querying the mapped value of task ':app:ktlintAndroidTestDebugSourceSetFormat' property 'reporterOutputDir' before task ':app:ktlintAndroidTestDebugSourceSetFormat' has completed is not supported
```

Answer (score 4):

This was fixed in a later version of the ktlint gradle plugin.  You can go down to `9.2.1` or up to `10.0.0`.  [See this issue](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle/issues/379).

Answer (score 0):

Updating to latest version of ktlint should be the solution to this issues for compatability